# Which is the path of registry key for copy options (selected text) in the right click menu on Windows?

Tags: windows, text, menu, contextmenu, selected

I'm working on a python project that can simply reverse the case of the selected text on a web browser interface.

For this project I need the path of the registry key for copy options in right click menu (when text is selected).

Anybody know what is the path of this key ? or how I could do for add my python program in the right click menu when text is selected ?

Thanks!

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? A right click menu is definitely application-specific. Moreover, if you don't share a [mcve] then your question seems to be off-topic here. Oh, sorry: _welcome to Stack Overflow_.

Comment: This is off-topic for stackoverflow. This would be much more likely to get a good answer on either server fault (https://serverfault.com/) or super user (https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Ok thanks for reply. In fact my request is the same that this topic : https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/50103-registry-key-controls-right-click-options-selected-text.html. But clearly serverfault.com or superuser.com are more appropriate. I will post on one of them sorry for that.